# How to show that the derivative of a function is integrable.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

In the fundamental theorem of Calculus, first we show by the mean value theorem that the derivative of the integral of a function is the function itself. Next we show that any two primitive functions of a function must differ by a constant. Thus we show that if the integral of a function exists then primitive functions of the function are the indefinite integrals of the function and vice versa.

Now, say we have a function which is differentiable. If we know that the derivative was integrable then we would be sure that the function is the integral of its derivative. But how do we show that the derivative is integrable??

Comment: This is not true. There are differentiable functions whose derivatives are not integrable. See eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function

Comment: Ohh!! So in general, the fundamental theorem of Calculus can be used only if I know that the derivative is integrable?

Comment: Note the derivative of a function is always Lebesque measurable though.